# How to get data in Angular 8 when only we have one object to be received

Tags: angular, api, http

The error I get:

> core.js:6260 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
>
> at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:4406)
>   at callHook (core.js:4762)
>   at callHooks (core.js:4722)
>   at executeCheckHooks (core.js:4642)
>   at refreshView (core.js:11979)
>   at refreshComponent (core.js:13449)
>   at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11689)
>   at refreshView (core.js:12024)
>   at refreshComponent (core.js:13449)
>   at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11689)

The code below works if I have more then one object. When the data is as shown below, and from that, I understand that something is wrong with array or object but I am unable to figure it out. So when I have 2 objects I get the data in the dropdown, but when it is one I get the error mentioned above.

```
[
{..},
{..}
]
```

My data Looks like this:

```
{
"details_id": 218,
"master_code": 218,
"MstCode": null,
"start_date": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
"end_date": "2020-02-29T00:00:00",
"canceled": "False   ",
"data_archived": null,
"last_updated_on": "2020-02-28 11:37:08",
"last_updated_by": null
}
```

My http get request code is as below:

```
this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id).toPromise().then(res => this.Details = res as TrDetails);
```

My model code:

```
export class TrDetails {
    details_id: number;
    master_code: number;
    MstCode: number;
    start_date: Date;
    end_date: Date;
    canceled: string;
    data_archived: string;
    last_updated_on: Date;
    last_updated_by: string;
}
```

My service code:

```
apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:2676/api/";
Details : TrainingDetails;

GetDetails(id){
    this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id).toPromise().then(res => 
    this.Details = res as TrDetails);
  }
```

My dropdown code:

```
<option *ngFor="let data of service.Details" [value]="data.start_date">{{data.program_start_date}}</option>
```

Comment: Can you show what you get when you `console.log(res)` inside the then method and where are you using `GetDetails` method

Comment: `data_archived: null
canceled: "False   "
last_updated_by: null
last_updated_on: "2020-02-28 11:31:58"
end_date: "2020-02-29T00:00:00"
start_date: "2020-02-29T00:00:00"
MstCode: null
details_id: 217
master_code: 1`

Comment: where are you using `GetDetails` method ?

Comment: in my component TypeScript File

Comment: and your dropdown code belongs to components html right

Comment: Did you `res.json()`

Comment: yes the dropdown belongs to component HTML.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi no let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to is this:

```
GetDetails(id){
    this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id).toPromise().then(res => 
    this.Details = res.json() as TrDetails);
  }
```

Updating the answer after some discussion:

If `res` was coming an object, you needed to convert this into an array, else if it's an array assign as it is. Also needed to `catch` if there's an error :

```
GetDetails(id){
    this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id).toPromise().then(res =>
    if(Array.isArray(res)){
        this.Details = res;
    }else{
        this.Details = [res] as any //change any to your type that matches
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: when I tried this I get an error. `Property json doesn't  exist on type object`

Comment: Ok so it's clear now, `res ` is an object and not an array. So `ngFor` wont work in that case. Try putting `*ngIf* to check it;s an array first

Comment: print the data with `console.log()`. Accordingly you can parse with `JSON.parse(res)` But first, we need to know what `res` is printing.

Comment: Btw did you try `res.json() as any` instead of `TrDetails `

Comment: how to check if the object is an array or object using `ngIf`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215016/discussion-between-rahul-dwivedi-and-p-mubeen).

Comment: Yes I did try `res.json()` but it gives an error that `json cannot be applied on type object`

Answer (score 1):

`service.Details` should be an array for *ngFor to work, it seems like the value of `service.Details` is an object here and hence you getting the error.

Ideally you should not subscribe within your service method, you should just return the observable from your service and subscribe it inside the component.

I recommend you to change your service method to this

```
 getDetails(id){
    return this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id);
 }
```

And inside your component wherever you are calling getDetails method you can do this

```
this.details = this.service.getDetails(id).pipe(map(res => [res]))
```

Then in your html you can simply use your async operator to subscribe.I would suggest to use observable pattern instead of promise pattern, this will make your code look more clean

```
<option *ngFor="let data of (details | async)" [value]="data.start_date">{{data.program_start_date}}</option>
```

Comment: yes, I figured that out but I don't know how to get the data.

Comment: You dont have to follow a promise pattern when you work with angular, angular gels well with observable pattern so you should follow that I would suggest, I have updated the ans, please check.

Comment: ok so just try this: `res => [res] || [];`, Thank you for the help but this solution worked and it was provided by @RahulDwivedi

Answer (score 1):

If your logic is working when the response is an array, you just need to add any object response to an empty array before using it. Try changing your GetDetails method body to below

```
this.http.get(this.apiBaseUrl+"ProgramDets/"+id).toPromise().then((res: TrDetails | TrDetails[]) => this.Details = Array.isArray(res) ? res : [res]);
```